# Unix Bourne-shell environment variable

Tags: unix

I want to create a .profile file that will have a welcome message everything I log in. However, I need to set the environment variable which I don't understand. Are you able to tell me what it does and how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

To display all environment variables and their values:

```
env
```

To change or set an environment variable:

```
export var=value
```

To remove an environment variable:

```
unset var
```

Typically, a welcome message can be shown by customizing the `/etc/motd` file to your liking. If you want, you can also add some messages in `/etc/profile` by using the `echo` or `print` commands.

For example:

```
echo "Welcome ${USER}"
```

or

```
echo "Welcome $(whoami)"
```

Comment: What I don't understand is what does the .profile got to do with environment variable?

Comment: You can add or reference environment variables from within .profile.

Comment: So what does "set environment variable in profile"?

Comment: In your .profile:
`VAR=value`

`VAR2=value2`

`export VAR VAR2`

Comment: No, I used `VAR` as an example of an environment variable you can create. All the current environment variables and their values can be displayed by entering the command `env` in the console.

Comment: So what is the purpose/benefit of setting a environment variable in the profile? Just want a good understanding.

Comment: For the same reasons any variable is set. By setting an environment variable in .profile, they are specific to you.

Comment: and you don't have to type in the variable assignments manually each time you start up a shell. (time wasting and highly subject to error ;-) ). Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
$ VAR=Hello
$ echo $VAR
```

Output:

> Hello

[Ref link.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell_Scripting/Environment#The_'set'_command)